# Unable to rezise partions with gparted

Tags: system-installation, uefi, gparted

`gparted` does not read partitions like `gnome-disk-utility`.  I installed  Windows 8 first to make UEFI partitions and then I installed Ubuntu 18.04.  I think the problem is with the installation of Windows 8; Once it's installed, `gparted` reads `sda` like udf.  Tis is my information about `/dev/sda`:

```
Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for udf file system support:  udftools.
```

[image: https://ibb.co/wpMqR8d]

[image: https://ibb.co/JrQDJJz]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, I found it, the problem was my partition table was wrong, I solved using Device===>Create a partition Table===>GPT and work well.

Solved problem.

Thanks to all.

[gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3e5h.png)